# Distribution of quantifiers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the statement ∃x(S(x)∧∀y(F(y)→A(x,y))), equivalent to ∃x∀y(S(x)∧F(y)→A(x,y))?

Since from ∃x∀y(S(x)∧F(y)→A(x,y)), you can distribute ∀y across the statement, obtaining, ∃x(∀yS(x)∧∀yF(y)→∀yA(x,y)).  Since x and y are not dependent, we obtain ∃x(S(x)∧∀yF(y)→∀yA(x,y)), which can be shortened to ∃x(S(x)∧∀y(F(y)→A(x,y))).  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct, just perform the reverse steps. As you note, it relies on the independence of the statements $x$ and $y$.